# how do I keep paypal, visa and mastercard images without links?

Tags: image, payment, footer

not a techie: but I have inherited a website(!): and am trying to keep paypal, mastercard and visa footer images without linking to the actual sites as per boss' instructions. In my static blocks, footer payment option block, here is the code:

```
<!--<p><a class="visa" href="#">Visa</a>
 <a class="amex" href="#">American Express</a>
 <a class="mastercard" href="#">Mastercard</a>
 <a class="discover" href="#">Discover</a>
 <a class="paypal" href="#">PayPal</a>
 <a class="2co" href="#">2 Checkout</a>
 <a class="skrill" href="#">Skrill</a>
 <a class="worldpay" href="#">Worldpay</a>
 <a class="google" href="#">Google Pay</a>
 <a class="amazon" href="#">Amazon</a>
 <a class="delta" href="#">Delta</a>-->

<p><a class="visa" href="https://www.visa.ie" target="blank">visa</a> <a class="paypal" href="https://www.paypal.com/ie" target="blank">PayPal</a> <a class="mastercard" href="https://www.mastercard.com/ie" target="blank">mastercard</a></p>
```

How do I keep images but not links? I've tried using the breaking link symbol on the editor, but that removes the image and am left with just the word paypal at frontend for example. Thanks a mill

Comment: Hi, Marius, thank u v much. I've just tried ur suggestion. Only thing is that when I click on it it brings me to the top of the Home Page. Don't suppose there's anyway to make it totally inert so that the above doesn't happen? Many thanks again C

Comment: If this is repeat, ignore pls, not sure if last comment registered or not. I tried that code and thanks a mill. It brings me to the top of the home page. Definite improvement, but don't suppose it's possible to make image totally inert? i.e. nothing to click on, just the image? Thanks for ur patience

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this. Adding the image tag in

```
<a class="paypal" href="#"><img title="Additional Options" alt="Additional Options" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/bnr/bnr_nowAccepting_150x60.gif"> </a>
```